# How to put each loop value into separate divs in django

Tags: html, css, django, django-views

[image]

Here's my html page. I want each 'question' to be placed in separate div to make them look nice.
So I put in the following code:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    <div class="myDiv">
    <a href="{% url 'article' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> <br>- {{ post.author }} , {{ post.date.date }}<br>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But here's what it did:

[image]

It makes one big div and placing all the posts/questions in them. How do I separate them?

Here's my css:

```
         .myDiv {
          background-color: #012B39;
          text-align: left;
          margin: left;
          width: 25%;
          }
```

Little help will be appreciated! THANKS

P.S I will change the font colors to make them visible with the div.

Comment: It's not one big div, check using inspect element in your browser. Your divs simply don't have any margin top or bottom and with the background color it looks like one big div.

Comment: U probably are right... Can u write an answer i can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that all the elements are rendered in one div. Your div's simply don't have any bottom / top margin and with the background color, It's looking like one div tag. You should check in the inspect element in your browser to make sure. A simple fix would be to add some bottom / top margin in your css:

```
.myDiv {
    background-color: #012B39;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Adjust the margin as per your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
You usually start the div before starting the loop.

```
<div class="myDiv">
{% for post in object_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'article' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> <br>- {{ post.author }} , {{ post.date.date }}<br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```